# Missing corner cases

Tags: algorithm, stack

Below is the link to problem
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/and-xor-or/copy-from/16519519

 I have implemented a O(n) solution which seems ok (no TLE and 29 testcaes passed out of 32). But my solution is failing for some testcaes and I am not able to find the error, surely I am missing some corner cases. Any hint would be great help. I have posted my code below which I have ran and submitted.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

#define ul unsigned long
using namespace std;


ul comp(ul a, ul b){
    ul result = ((a&b)^(a|b))&(a^b);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<ul>ip(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>ip[i];
    stack<ul>st;
    ul result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(st.empty())
            st.push(ip[i]);
        else{
            result=max(result,comp(st.top(),ip[i]));
            while(!st.empty() && st.top()>ip[i]){
                result=max(result,comp(st.top(),ip[i]));
                st.pop();
            }
            st.push(ip[i]);
        }
    }
    cout<<result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JoopEggen I'm afraid not. Code Review reviews **code that is already working as intended**. This is not.

Comment: Sorry assumed "corner cases" not to be that important. Shame on me as production programmer.

Comment: The `comp` expression can be simplified to `a xor b`. It might help to print a trace to get to know which array elements are taken to calculate the function value.